# Any script to auto-click on a link of a class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to make an extension for chrome, so that when loading a certain page, it auto clicks on a link (which is inside a "href ="). The page has a count before generating a link (link unknown).

This is the element string before generating the link after using the option "inspect element":

```
<a href="javascript: void(0)" class="btn btn-primary btn-goo get-link disabled"> Preparing link ... </a>
```

And so it ends after the count:

```
 <a href="https://123.com/123" class="btn btn-primary btn-goo get-link">Get Link <i class="lnr lnr-arrow-right"></i></a>
```

I'm not an expert, but I suppose the only reference I have of that "href" is "class" since it doesn't have "id". I look for that once the link is generated, it will open in a new tab automatically.

I've tried everything and still don't know what I'm doing wrong. 
I imagined using something like the xpath but it seemed even more complicated.

Comment: `document.querySelector('.btn.btn-primary.btn-goo.get-link')`

Comment: `$("a.btn.get-link").click()` or `$(".lnr-arrow").closest("a").click()` if you want the one after it's changed